# Nginx - IP address does not change to Hostname

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, guacamole

I'm beginner to Nginx and need a help on IP address.

I use the nginx docker container to access Guacamole (also a docker container), somehow I managed to give an IP address with Hostname (fqdn). when I type the ip address and press enter it takes me to the guacamole site same happens when I type the hostname. My problem is the IP address remains the same; it doesn't change to the Hostname in search bar.

For example:

the ip address is 123.123.123.123:8080, when I enter this ip in search bar, it enters to the webpage but the IP does not change to Hostname (local.domain.com).
[IP Address (it still remains same and doesn't change to hostname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnRON.png)

But, when i enter the Hostname (fqdn) it goes to webpage and it display the hostname.
[Hostname belonged to the ipaddress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUzay.png)

Comment: That seems normal to me.  You don't seem to have included any of your source code in the question, though: can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], highlighting what part you expect to cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the default behavior of browsers.

#### Scenario 1: Enter hostname

When you enter hostname in the browser search bar, browser will initiate **DNS lookup** and translate the hostname into IP Address. It is a process of converting human read-able domain name into computer read-able IP Address.

#### Scenario 2: Enter IP Address

By default, browser doesn't do **DNS reverse lookup**. This is the reason why you would see IP address input is still displaying as IP address instead of domain. DNS reverse lookup is a process which translate IP address back to domain. This is the opposite of a regular DNS lookup.

There are a few reasons why browser doesn't do DNS reverse lookup.

- Not always necessary (browser only needs IP address to reach your server)
- DNS reverse lookup can be slow
- DNS reverse lookup can be unreliable sometimes when PTR records are missing